# wstringstream to LPWSTR

Tags: c++, wchar-t, string-conversion

I have built up a string using `wstringstream` and need to assign it to a member of a `struct` of type `LPWSTR`. I try to use `my_stringstream.str().c_str()` but get the following compile time error:

> cannot convert from 'const wchar_t *' to 'LPWSTR'

How can I do this? I have tried many different combinations of casts with either more compile time errors or random jargon when I try and display the string in a GUI.

Comment: `LPWSTR` is a typedef for `wchar_t*`, I believe, so you require a pointer to non-const. Make a copy of your string to a mutable memory area. Or double-check your consumer function why it needs a mutable string, maybe that's an error.

Comment: By the way, what `struct` are you trying to fill?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your function expects a pointer to modifiable data, i.e. `wchar_t*`, but the standard string class only exposes a pointer to constant. Assuming that your function may actually write to the memory, we need to provide it with a valid pointer.

An easy way to obtain a modifiable buffer is, as always, a `vector`:

```
std::vector<wchar_t> buf(mystring.begin(), mystring.end());
buf.push_back(0);                 // because your consumer expects null-termination

crazy_function(buf.data());
crazy_function(&buf[0]);          // old-style

// need a string again?
std::wstring newstr(buf.data());  // or &buf[0]
```

Comment: On the other hand, this do not account the case where `crazy_function` shortened the string writing a `L'\0'` before `buf.end()`. I think that it's better to simply rebuild `newstr` with the usual C string constructor (`std::wstring newstr(&buf[0])`).

Answer (score 7):

`LPWSTR` is `typedef`d as `wchar_t*`. You're trying to convert a `const wchar_t*` to a `wchar_t*`. You can't do that implicitly.

You can get around this by using `const_cast`, but only if you are certain the function won't modify the memory:

```
wstring str = my_stringstream.str();
LPWSTR str = const_cast<LPWSTR>(str.c_str());
```

Note that you **do not want to do** `const_cast<LPWSTR>(my_stringstream.str().c_str())` (unless you are passing that to a function) because that will create a temporary string object, get it's pointer, convert it to a `LPWSTR` and then the temporary string you get from `str()` will be destroyed at the end of that line, leaving your `LPWSTR` pointing to a deallocated block of memory.

If the function you are passing the `LPWSTR` to *is* modifying the string, see [Kerrek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264690/wstringstream-to-lpwstr/7264765#7264765).

Answer (score 1):

If you are absolutely sure that the content of the string will not be modified, you can cast the `const` away via a `static_cast`; a situation where this can be acceptable for example is if you are using some `struct` to provide data to a function, but the same `struct` is also used for retrieving it, so that member is `LPWSTR` instead of just an `LPCWSTR`.

If, on the contrary, the function to which you'll pass the `struct` needs to modify the string, you have two alternatives.

The safest one is to allocate a separate copy of the string as a raw dynamic array of `WCHAR` and copy there the content of the `wstring`. You will probably want to wrap the result of the `new` with a smart pointer, unless you're transferring the ownership of the string (and in that case you'll probably have to use some special allocation function).

You can also pass a pointer to the internal buffer of the string using `&YourString[0]`, but (1) I'm not sure it's guaranteed to work by the standard, and (2) it works fine only if the function won't change the length of your string adding a `L'\0'` before the end of it; in this case you should also re-adjust the actual length of the string.

Both in the last and in the first case you must be sure that the function you're passing the `struct` to do not expect the pointed buffer to live longer than the scope of your `wstring` (careful: `mystream.str()` is a temporary that dies on the very line you use it, you have to assign it to a new variable to give it a broader scope).

Answer (score 1):

```
  wstringstream b;
    ..
    wchar_t z[100];
    b.read(z,100);
```

where string length known to be less then 101. 
it works without `unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws)` and all this. And without `ZeroMemory` on wchar_t array.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is rather simple: `LPWSTR` expands to `wchar_t *`. As the pointer to the stream contents is a `const`, it's not possible to cast this `const` away, unless using `const_cast<LPWSTR>(my_stringstream.str().c_str())`. However I'd advice against this (as you might simply screw this up and/or modify something different that way. Only do it if you're sure it won't be modified or the modification won't matter.

The easiest (and most secure solution) is to create your own copy of the string provided by the `wstringstream` in a buffer and refer to this one in the struct. Just don't forget to free the memory later on.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::wstring temp(my_stringstream.str());
lpwstrVar = &temp[0];
```