# Using CreateProcessW with non-ascii characters in application path

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to call CreateProcessW and execute a `helloworld.exe` file located under `C:\Users\name_with_é\helloworld.exe`(`helloworld.exe` prints "Hello world" to the console). I'm using MSVC on windows 10, 64bits:

```
wstring cmd = L"C:\\Users\\name_with_é\\helloworld.exe";
vector<wchar_t> buf(cmd.begin(), cmd.end());
buf.push_back(0);
BOOL result = CreateProcess(NULL, buf.data(), NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
if (!result)
{
    wcout << "could not create process " << buf.data();
    cout << GetLastError();
}
```

With this code, CreateProcessW returns false, and GetLastError() returns 2 (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND), even if `helloworld.exe` is present.

However, `wcout << buf.data()` gives `C:\Users\name_with_├®\helloworld.exe`. So I have an encoding problem (and I believe it causes the ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error) , but how to solve it ?

I set up Visual Studio to use the Unicode charset, but as far as I looked, using utf-8 on windows is not trivial...

Comment: As with any text file, the program that reads it must use the same character encoding that was used to write it. In this case, the compiler's [`/execution-charset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/execution-charset-set-execution-character-set?view=vs-2019) (or equiv) must match what your source code editor is using. Visual Studio normally sets this up correctly, but it's worth checking.

Comment: `CreateProcessW` should work fine. Make sure your *.cpp file is saved in Unicode format and you have copy/pasted the right name in to *.cpp file. You can also use `cmd.data()` if compiler supports it.

Comment: It's a shame `\u00E9` doesn't work in a wide string literal :( BTW that vector is completely unnecessary; `cmd.c_str()` is already the null-terminated wide string that you want.

Comment: Both `cmd.data()` and `cmd.c_str()` return a `const wchar_t*`, and I need a `LPWSTR`. I found this Kerrek SB answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7264765 . My .cpp file is saved with UTF-8, and I set Properties ->General->Charset to "Use Unicode charset" in VS properties, but I don't know if it is suficient or if there is another option to modify.

Comment: To ensure printing to the console via `wcout << buf.data()` shows the right characters, at startup call `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)` (include io.h and fcntl.h).

Comment: Don't use `cmd.c_str()`, use `&cmd[0]` IIRC and you'll avoid needing to copy, and you'll have a null terminator also ....

Comment: To diagnose the issue, run Process Monitor and see what executable is really accessed. Besides, since you aren't passing any command line arguments, don't use the command line parameter of `CreateProcessW`. If you do, make sure to properly quote. Also, as seems to be the case almost everywhere: Your call to `GetLastError` returns a meaningless value. You are calling it way too late.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan note that using `&cmd[0]` requires the `std::wstring`'s internal buffer to be null-terminated, which is not guaranteed prior to C++11. I would just call `push_back(0)` on the `std::wstring` itself to force a null-terminator: `wstring cmd = L"..."; cmd.push_back(0); CreateProcessW(..., &cmd[0], ...);`

Comment: @Remy Well, if you are using an out of date compiler.....

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sadly, I am, and I have no choice about that :-(

Comment: Thanks for all your comments ! @eryksun : after adding this line, "é" is now displayed as "Ã©" instead of "├®". @IInspectable : Process Monitor reports a `CreateFile` operation on `C:\Users\name_with_Ã©\helloworld.exe` and `C:\Users\name_with_Ã©\helloworld.exe.exe`, hence the file_not_found_error imo. Also, where shloud I put my call to `GetLastError()` ?

Comment: @rem: The complexity of `c_str()` has always been O(1). Unless you are targeting some very, very weird architecture, that allows you to map arbitrary values at arbitrary addresses (in constant time), under arbitrary conditions, you can rely on the fact that the stored sequence of a `std::string` is zero-terminated.

Comment: @EinderJam, your source file is saved as UTF-8, in which "é" is `"\xc3\xa9"`, apparently without a BOM. The compiler defaults the source character set to the ANSI codepage. (The execution character set is not relevant here since it's a wide-character string literal.) In your case, the ANSI codepage is 1252. Use the [`/utf-8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=vs-2019) compiler option to compile UTF-8 source files that don't have a UTF-8 BOM.

Comment: @IInspectable But CreateProcessW needs an editable array and c_str does not provide one

Comment: @dav: The OP isn't passing any command line arguments, so they could just use the first argument, one that doesn't expect a modifiable buffer. Regardless, I was commenting on the statement that it were not guaranteed, that `string` would store a zero terminator, which - in practice - it does. Even pre C++11.

Comment: @IInspectable OK, I get you

Comment: If your source file is UTF-8 encoded, have you tried to save it with BOM?

Comment: @eryksun Yes, I described the need for source-charset to be matching but I mistakenly linked the execution charset.

Comment: By testing: switching from UTF-8 to UTF-8 with BOM may solve the problem.

Comment: @eryksun you were right ! adding `/utf-8` to compiler options solved my problem ! According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=vs-2019, `/utf-8` sets both Source and executable character sets to UTF-8 with VS.

Comment: In this case the execution character set isn't relevant. That's for `char` string literals, not wide-character string literals. Nowadays C++ has the `u8` prefix to force UTF-8 for a `char` string literal. It also has `u` (`char16_t`) and `U` (`char32_t`) alternatives to `L` (`wchar_t`). See [String and Character Literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @eryksun,Since the problem has been solved, could you please add an answer for details to help people with the same problem.